# SQL Multiple Select on same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currrently stuck with my sql query.

I want to do multiple select query but all in one. Each select is for the same table, same column but have different conditions.

I'm using this for the moment :

```
    /* Ordre d'affichage 1 */
    $sql = "SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION, O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres FROM OffreEmploi O, Diffuseur D WHERE O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND O.ID_DIFFUSEUR = D.Id AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ";
    /* Ordre d'affichage 2 */
    $sql .= "EXCEPT ";
    $sql .="SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION, O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres FROM OffreEmploi O, Diffuseur D WHERE O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND O.ID_DIFFUSEUR = D.Id AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ";
    /* Ordre d'affichage 3 */
    $sql .= "EXCEPT ";
    $sql .="SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION, O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres FROM OffreEmploi O, Diffuseur D WHERE O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND O.ID_DIFFUSEUR = D.Id AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ";
    /* Ordre d'affichage 4 */   
    $sql .= "EXCEPT ";
    $sql .="SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION, O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres FROM OffreEmploi O, Diffuseur D WHERE O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.ID_DIFFUSEUR = D.Id AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1 ";
    /* Ordre d'affichage 5 */
    $sql = "SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION, O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres FROM OffreEmploi O, Diffuseur D WHERE O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat ";
    $sql .= "EXCEPT ";
    /* Ordre d'affichage 6 */
    $sql = "SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION, O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres FROM OffreEmploi O, Diffuseur D WHERE O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat ";
```

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($_POST['intitule'], $_POST['intitule']));

Is there a way to make this easier and possible? (because currently the except does not work)

Comment: Have you considered UNION?

Comment: Still struggling? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: UNION didn't work too, will try NOT IN, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you do this as one long `where` clause:

```
SELECT O.INTITULE, O.ENTREPRISENOM, O.TYPECONTRAT, O.DATEDEBUT, O.DATEINSERTION, O.REGION,
       O.FONCTION, O.ID_DIFFUSEUR, D.Id, D.MiseEnAvantOffres
FROM OffreEmploi O join
     Diffuseur D
     on O.ID_DIFFUSEUR = D.Id 
WHERE (O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1) and
      not (O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1) and
      not (O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1) and
      not (O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND D.MiseEnAvantOffres = 1) and
      not (O.INTITULE = ? AND O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat) and
      not (O.REGION = $regions AND O.FONCTION = $fonctions AND O.TYPECONTRAT = $type_contrat);
```

The last two are missing the (implicit) join conditions in the `where` clauses.  If you were having problems, that could have been the cause.  You should learn to always use explicit joins.